# Test Automation: How to simulate power failure/machine crash?

Tags: windows, testing, automated-tests

I have a delphi application that relies on SQLite3, a DB engine that's advertised as crash-proof.

So far I was able to make my whole application crash-proof, but now I need to simulate brutal machine reboot / power failure.

Obviously it would crazy/unpractical to brutally reboot my machine 100 times / per day just to conduct this test, so...

**I wonder if there's a way to simulate power failure using VirtualBox (or something similar) programmatically / in an automated fashion**?

Any other method/thought would be more than welcome, my goal is to make sure my users' data is never corrupted.

PS. This question is for Windows XP or later

Comment: Writing a crash-proof app is a tall order ;) To address your question though:

Yes, it is quite easy to automate the shutting down of a VM - for instance by passing arguments to the VM controller according to its documentation.

For VirtualBox that would be the VBoxManage controlvm verb as described here: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running this on the virtual box host should do the trick

VBoxManage controlvm (vmname) reset/poweroff

> VBoxManage controlvm (vmname) reset has the same effect on a virtual
>   machine as pressing the "Reset" button on a real computer: a cold
>   reboot of the virtual machine, which will restart and boot the guest
>   operating system again immediately. The state of the VM is not saved
>   beforehand, and data may be lost. (This is equivalent to selecting the
>   "Reset" item in the "Machine" menu of the GUI.)
>
> VBoxManage controlvm (vmname) poweroff has the same effect on a virtual
>   machine as pulling the power cable on a real computer. Again, the
>   state of the VM is not saved beforehand, and data may be lost. (This
>   is equivalent to selecting the "Close" item in the "Machine" menu of
>   the GUI or pressing the window's close button, and then selecting
>   "Power off the machine" in the dialog.)

Comment: That's bold claim. Hard drives and even sata conroller are still powered on. More to say, even on pressing reset hard drives are still powered on.