# Simulate Power Failure for Debugging Purposes

Tags: java, linux, debugging

I have a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126465/how-are-these-methods-allowing-causing-data-to-be-lost-on-disk) that appears only when power is abruptly lost. Shutting down the machine doesn't trigger it, but a power outage or unplugging the power strip at the wall does.

I would like to work on this bug, and to do so it would be really nice to have some way to simulate a power outage like this (perhaps in  a tool like VirtualBox) without having to reset the machine every test.

Is there any way you know of on linux to simulate this so I can try to isolate this bug?

Comment: Kill the process by sending a `SIGKILL` signal, e.g. using command-line `kill -9 <processid>`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't work -- the bug doesn't manifest. I think the issue is somehow related to the file system being taken down while the program is shutting down. Or something. :shrugs confused:

Comment: Oops! I found an answer for this already on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910565/test-automation-how-to-simulate-power-failure-machine-crash